# DRF how to call an api without the the queruset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a rest API in DRF without any DB. I want the user to hit the API with the post data. Once the system receives the data I will do another API call and show the response. My code is:

serializers.py

```
class getCPHSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    cph_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True)
```

views.py

```
class GETCPHDetails(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cphID = request.data.get('cphID',None)
        errorList = []

        if not cphID:
            errorList.append({"message": "No CPH Found"})

        if len(errorList) == 0:
             param = {"searchQry": cphID}
             apiResponse = requests.post("http://172.61.25.40:8000/api/newSearch", data=param )
             return Response({"message":json.loads(apiResponse)})
```

I am getting an error

> Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Any suggestion will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [**`APIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you are not returning a response when

`len(errorList) == 0` is `False`

Python will always return `None` if you don't return anything
from a method.